# Is $u_x(0,t)=u_x(1,t)=u_t(x,0)=u_t(x, 1) = 0$ an example of Neumann boundary conditions?

Tags: boundary-value-problem

I am unsure if this qualifies. The examples I have seen have all had nonzero boundary conditions. If it matters, I am solving the wave equation $c^2u_{xx} = u_{tt}$.

Comment: Yes, they are Neumann BC.